# StackOverflow while traversing map with a record a key type

Tags: f#

I am new to F#. Hence, maybe I am missing something here. However, executing the following snippet results in a StackOverflowException:

```
type Node = { 
    Position: int*int
    mutable North: Node option 
    mutable South: Node option 
    mutable West:  Node option
    mutable East:  Node option }
let initialNode = { Position = 0, 0; North = None; South = None; West = None; East = None }

let second = { Position = -1, 0; North = None; South = None; West = None; East = None }
initialNode.West <- Some second
second.East <- Some initialNode
let third = { Position = -1, -1; North = None; South = None; West = None; East = None }
second.North <- Some third
third.South <- Some second
let fourth = { Position = -1, 0; North = None; South = None; West = None; East = None }
third.East <- Some fourth
fourth.West <- Some third

let distanceMap = Map.empty |> Map.add initialNode 0
let needVisit = [ initialNode ]

let newDistanceMap =
    (distanceMap, needVisit)
    ||> Seq.fold (fun map node ->
         map |> Map.add node 1)

newDistanceMap |> Map.count
```

Why?
If the key type of the map is changed to the `Position` attribute (which is a `Tuple`) of the record type everything is fine. Hence, I suspect the issue is using records as key type in general or the issue is using record types which have `mutable` attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hence, I suspect the issue is using records as key type in general or the issue is using record types which have mutable attributes.

It's reference loops (which strictly speaking don't require `mutable` attributes in the records themselves). To calculate hash code of a record, all of its fields' hash codes are used. So to calculate hash code of `initialNode`, you need to know `initialNode.West`'s hash code, which uses `second`'s, which uses `second.East`'s, which uses `initialNode`'s, which... etc. etc.

I don't think you can customize a record's `GetHashCode()` method, though I am not sure.

Note that equality comparison can run into the same trouble (imagine moving `Position` to the end first).

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not directly related to the key being mutable, but to the fact that you have cycles (initial -> second -> initial -> ...). If you comment out lines that create cycles it will work.

Like Alexey suggests you could work around this by customizing GetHashCode/Equality for your type or change representation of your data.

This is in fact inherent limitation of immutable data types: you can't represent cycle in such straightforward way. If you want to work with such graphs in F# and avoid too much mutability I propose you look into some other way to represent graphs like [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), for more in depth analysis try googling inductive graphs.

Comment: Both @Alexey Romanov and you are right and the answers make alot of sense to me now. Alexey was first, hence I marked his answer. Thanks alot. I commented out the lines which form a cycle like you suggested and it really solved the StackOverflowException issue. Your answers will help me alot in future.